# AWS Glue - User did not initialize spark context

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I am working in AWS glue.i am reading a hive metastore based table from AWS Glue Catalog from spark scala job in AWS glue with my custom spark code, please note i am writing my own code its our need. Code is working as expected, it is reading source table and loading to target table as well but still job goes to error every time.

**Here is my sparksession**

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SPARK-Dev")
                            .master("local[*]")
                            .enableHiveSupport()
                            .getOrCreate
```

**Job throws this error**

```
 2020-03-27 17:07:53,282 ERROR [main] yarn.ApplicationMaster (Logging.scala:logError(91)) - Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User did not initialize spark context!
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:779)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:778)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
```

Comment: if you give full error stack users can help you to debug.

Comment: full error stack has been updated

Comment: I don't see you created sparkcontext. Refer to https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/JoinAndRelationalize.scala  and use below code to create it :    import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JsonOptions
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.{DynamicFrame, GlueContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object JoinAndRelationalize {
  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext()
    val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(sc)

Comment: I am not using GlueContext or Glue dynamicframes etc. , still i need to initialze it?

Answer (score 0):

You're are using `master("local[*]")`. I'm not sure that it's correct with cluster. Try to use it withought master func